# Unity: VideoPlayer freezes for half of a second with .webm video

Tags: unity-game-engine, webm, alpha-transparency

I'm using windows 10 Pro and unity 5.6.4p2.
I've 2 planes with a videoplayer component (both videos are loaded from the streaming assets folder. One video is a .mp4 and the other is a .webm with transparency (alpha channel).
I've some scripts attached to the planes but I've this problem with and without scripts, so there is no need to post the code.

The webm video (6 seconds long) play in loop and every 10-15-20 or more seconds it freezes for half of a second. With the mp4 video I don't have problems.

In the Editor there are no freeze, when I try it on a build it gives me the problem.

I don't know what to do. Is there something that I can try with the quality options on Unity? I tried 5 different videos with transparency (webm) but They were make by the same person with the same method. Could be the file?

In the meanwhile I'm looking for another .webm for some tests.

Thank you!

EDIT (code for playing the video):

```
IEnumerator playVideo(string name)
    {
        blackScreen.SetActive (true);
        wait = true;

        videoPlayer = gameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        //Disable Play on Awake for both Video and Audio
        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;
        audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
        audioSource.Pause();

        videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
        if (!alpha) {
            videoPlayer.url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Scenarios/" + 
    name + ".mp4";
        } else {
            videoPlayer.url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Scenarios/" + 
    name + ".webm";
        }
        videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
        videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);

        //Set video To Play then prepare Audio to prevent Buffering
        videoPlayer.clip = videoToPlay;
        currentVideoName = name;
        videoPlayer.Prepare();

        //Wait until video is prepared
        WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        while (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
        {
            Debug.Log("Preparing Video");

            yield return waitTime;

            break;
        }

        Debug.Log("Done Preparing Video");
        videoPlayer.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().enabled = true;
        blackScreen.SetActive (false);
        //Assign the Texture from Video to RawImage to be displayed
        image.texture = videoPlayer.texture;

        //Play Video
        videoPlayer.Play();
        ready = true;
        //Play Sound
        audioSource.Play();
        Debug.Log("Playing Video");
        while (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
        {
            wait = true;
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Done Playing Video");
        wait = false;
    }
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to play the video

Comment: HI! I posted the code, but it's a code based on one found here, and that I used in many projects so it should work. The problem exists even without the code...

Comment: Another "strange" fact is that webm video starts few seconds after the mp4 video even if I start them together in the start().

Comment: That's likely a bug.  5.6.4p2. is old. You need to update.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Is the 2018 version stable? Or should I use an older version?

Comment: Use the latest 2018 version. That should solve your issue. Make a copy of the project first so that you can roll back if there is a problem